# Count all signs, not white signs, all words and lines from char array in C

Tags: c, function, nlp

I get a task. I must write a program consists of several functions to analyze text (count words, signs, lines, not white signs etc.) This is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int allSigns(char text[])
{

    int i;
    for (i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; ++i);    
    return i;
}

int notWhiteSigns(char text[])
{
    int sum;
    for (int i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        if (text[i] != (' ' && '\n' && '\t'))
            sum++;
    }
    return sum;
}

int words(char text[])
{
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; text[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        if (text[i] == ' ' && text[i-1] && text[i] != ('\t' && '\n'))
            sum++;
    }
    if (text[i-1] != ' ');
        sum++;
    return sum;
}

int lines(char text[])
{
    int i;
    int sum = 1;
    for (int i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        if (text[i] == '\n')
            sum++;
    }
    return sum;
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char sentence[] = "C is \n a \n programming \t language";

    printf("Show array: %s \n", sentence);

    printf("All signs: %i\n not white signs: %i\n words: %i\n lines: %i\n", allSigns(sentence), notWhiteSigns(sentence), words(sentence), lines(sentence));


    return 0;
}
```

My output is:

```
Show array: C is 
 a 
 programming     language 
All signs: 33
 not white signs: 66
 words: 8
 lines: 3
```

I see that I made some mistakes. Lines is ok (3). But I have **8** words instead of **5** words. Function that count all words is ok (I count \n and \t as one). I dont know why I have **66 "not white signs"** (all signs except ' ', '\n', '\t',) I should have 23

Comment: This does not what you expect it to do: `text[i] != (' ' && '\n' && '\t')`. You cannot compare with different values at once. You need to compare with each value and combine the result of each comparison. What this expression actually does is `text[i] != (1)` because `' ' && '\n' && '\t'` (logical AND of non-false integer literals) is TRUE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is here:

```c
if (text[i] != (' ' && '\n' && '\t'))
```

Each character in `(' ' && '\n' && '\t')` will be represented as ASCII code. So this expression means `(text[i] != (32 && 10 && 9))`.

Try this instead:

```c
if ((text[i] != ' ') && (text[i] != '\n') && (text[i] != '\t'))
```

You also should initialize `sum` variable before use.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize sum with zero and change the if statement:

```
int notWhiteSigns(char text[])
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        {
            if (text[i] != ' ' && text[i] != '\n' && text[i] != '\t')
                sum++;
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

in your code you have used two uninitialized variable:

first `sum` in function `int notWhiteSigns(char text[])` which need to be `int sum=0`.

second here:

```
int words(char text[])
{
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; text[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        if ((text[i] != ' ') && (text[i] != '\n') && (text[i] != '\t'))
            sum++;
    }
    if (text[i - 1] != ' ');
    sum++;
    return sum;
}
```

since you have re declared `i` in `for-loop` you won't have it's value outside of loop , and so here `if (text[i - 1] != ' ');` you are using uninitialized `i` remove `int i` from for loop `for (i = 1; text[i] != '\0'; ++i)`

also as mentioned it's wrong to compare `Text i` with different values at once.

this should be `if ((text[i] != ' ') && (text[i] != '\n') && (text[i] != '\t'))`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you function notwhiteSpace works correct. I found solution for counting words function

```
int words(char text[])
{
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; text[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        if (text[i] == ' ' && text[i-1] != ' ' && (text[i] != '\n') && (text[i] != '\t') && (text[i-1] != '\n') && (text[i-1] != '\t'))
            sum++;
    }
    if (text[i-1] != ' ');
        sum++;
    return sum;
}
```

Now it works properly